# How can I resolve the error in Transit mode code of Google Map in PHP

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hey freineds my code of google map in php is working for all other modes of travel(driving,walking, bycycling )other than Transit mode.I found the mistake in calculating the time taken to reach the destTination . My code in PHP :

```
   <?php
   $infos = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Guildford,+Surrey&destinations=Embankment,+London&mode=walking'));
   print_r($infos->rows[0]->elements[0]->duration);
   ?>
```

Please help me my freinds.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `transit` mode in the Google Distance Matrix API.

> `mode` — specifies the mode of transport to use when calculating directions. **Valid values are**:
>
> `driving` (default) indicates standard driving directions using the road network.
>
> `walking` requests walking directions via pedestrian paths & sidewalks (where available).
>
> `bicycling` requests bicycling directions via bicycle paths & preferred streets (currently only available in the US and some Canadian cities).

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#DistanceMatrixRequests